# Display fragmentation on Freya 0.3.1 (64 bit)

Tags: display

I am experiencing difficulties with the display due to triangular fragmentation, and can't use the OS at all yet, the glitching is so bad that most windows are obscured at least partially by a triangular shape. These shapes follow and distort as a window is moved about.

I use an HP 5730 thin client, with 1gb ram, 24gb HD, ATI x1250 video.

I have tried many other versions of linux on this machine, but have not seen this display corruption before, on any of them.

Thanks for your help.